# Kotlinc command line error

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

I follow this (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) instruction. I set the environment variable (windows 7) to bin directory run "kotlinc" at the command line i get the following error (I even navigate to the bin directory from the command prompt)

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.jetbrains.kotlin.preloading.Preloader

Comment: [This might be related](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-run-kotlin-1-1-4-eap-repl/3808/2), I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the compiler version is 1.2.10.(your link version is 1.1.4) downloaded from the link provided by the above doc page

Comment: why do you kotlinc? why not just gradle or maven?

Comment: @knock I wanted to compile the basic code from the doc page, do I need gradle or maven to do that (and will gradle or maven work without the kotlinc command working)

Answer (score 1):

its because spaces in path to kotlinc. Need to convert path from D:/Program Files to D:/.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file for hello.jar does not point to main() anymore. I've been asking about this for awhile -- it may have been broken since Kotlin 1.1.